# Theme engine missing?

Tags: python, themes, xfce

In xfce, specifically xubuntu 16.04, where are the theme engines found? I'm chasing a persistent error that gives warnings on each execution of a python program which imports pygtk. My desktop theme is probably a leftover from gtk 2, which may be the problem, but I've not been able to locate such engines in any of the gtk 3 themes installed by default, either.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found it; it's in a stanza of the theme's "gtkrc" file in its gtk-2.0 directory. I've edited that line to replace the engine name shown by the warning message, with "none" to verify -- but I still need to learn more about the intricacies of theme design and troubleshooting. As a toolmaker, I can never learn enough! A link to a howto for gtk-3 themes would be helpful...

LATER: Well, all that did was to change one word in the error messages, which come from GTK at the creation of a new toplevel window. I'll try commenting out the entire stanza from the css file and see what that does.